# test cypress con componente de primeVue

Tags: vue.js, vue3, testing, cypress, primevue

estoy haciendo un test component en cypress para un proyecto con vue y con la dependencia de la librería de Prime Vue, a la hora de ejecutar el test, me da el error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

He importado la librería y algunos elementos si se ven, pero su funcionalidad no funciona y lanza el error anterior continuamente.

He configurado el archivo component.js y tengo dudas si se están añadiendo correctamente las propiedades por defecto de Prime Vue:

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import '@/styles/index.scss';
import './commands';
import Paginator from 'primevue/paginator';
import Toolbar from 'primevue/toolbar';
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable';
import Column from 'primevue/column';
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import Dialog from 'primevue/dialog';




import {mount} from 'cypress/vue';
import mainVueOptions from '@/pages/_root/main.js';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options = {}) => {
  // Setup options object
  options.global = options.global || {};
  options.global.components = options.global.components || {};
  options.global.options = options.global.options || {};
  options.global.options['PrimeVue'] = PrimeVue;

  // Register global components
  options.global.components['Dropdown'] = Dropdown;
  options.global.components['DataTable'] = DataTable;
  options.global.components['Paginator'] = Paginator;
  options.global.components['Column'] = Column;
  options.global.components['Button'] = Button;
  options.global.components['Toolbar'] = Toolbar;
  options.global.components['Dialog'] = Dialog;
  return mount(component, options);
});
```

¿Alguien puede decirme si es correcto? Gracias

Comment: El error `Cannot read properties of undefined`, ¿no te menciona cuál es el objeto al cual no se puede leer sus propiedades?